# calculate height and apply to a div with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, height

I have a banner image that is only visible when i set a fixed height, i want to make it responsive so the only way i thought of doing that is calculating the height of the image with the width of the window.

the function to calculate the height is: windowWidth/1.845

how do i apply that function to a div css with jquery/javascript?

i tried this function but it didn't work

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
  var originalWidth = $( window ).width();
  var newHeight = originalWidth/+(1.845)
; 


  function resize() {
    $("#ei-slider").css("height", newHeight); 

  }

  $(".target").each(resize);
  $(document).resize(function(){
      $("ei-slider").each(resize);
  });
});
```

Comment: Whats are the dimensions of your banner?

Comment: are you missing `$("ei-slider").each(resize);` something on here? `.` before `ei-slider`?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding () when you call your function resize

```
$(".target").each(resize());
  $(document).resize(function(){
      $(".ei-slider").each(resize());
  });
```

Also, you miss the point before ei-slider

And I highly recommend to you to use backstretch jquery plugin.
http://srobbin.com/jquery-plugins/backstretch/

Comment: it worked ( the code ) but just the first time it load the page! when i resize it doesn't change! anyway, that was a huge help, thank you a lot rolo!

Answer (score 0):

Why is the image only visible when you set a fixed height? An image would be "responsive" automatically if you were to do this in your CSS.

```
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

However if you need to do other things in the resize you probably want to listen for resizes on `window` and not `document`.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  var $window = $(window);
  var originalWidth = $window.width();
  var newHeight = originalWidth / 1.845; 

  function resize() {
    // This will be .target or .ei-slider based on where it's called.
    $(this).css("height", newHeight);
  };

  $(".target").each(resize);

  $window.on('resize', function(){
      $(".ei-slider").each(resize);
  });

});
```